# How to route, group, or otherwise split up messages into consistent sets using TPL Dataflow

Tags: tpl-dataflow, akka.net, consistent-hashing

I'm new to **TPL Dataflow** and I'm looking for a construct which will allow splitting up a list of source messages for evenly distributed parallel processing while maintaining order of the messages message through individual pipelines. Is there a specific Block or concept within the DataFlow API that can be used to accomplish this or is it more of a matter providing glue code or custom Blocks between existing Blocks?

For those familiar with [Akka.NET](http://getakka.net/) I'm looking for functionality similar to the [ConsistentHashing router](http://getakka.net/docs/working-with-actors/Routers#consistenthashing) which allow sending messages to a single router which then forwards these messages on to individual routees to be handled.

Synchronous example:

```
var count = 100000;
var processingGroups = 5;
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

// Distribute source elements consistently and evenly into a specified set of groups (ex. 5) so that.
var distributed = source.GroupBy(s => s % processingGroups);

// Within each of the 5 processing groups go through each item and add 1 to it
var transformed = distributed.Select(d => d.Select(i => i + 3).ToArray());

List<int[]> result = transformed.ToList();
Check.That(result.Count).IsEqualTo(processingGroups);
for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
{
    var outputGroup = result[i];

    var expectedRange = Enumerable.Range(i + 1, count/processingGroups).Select((e, index) => e + (index * (processingGroups - 1)) + 3);
    Check.That(outputGroup).ContainsExactly(expectedRange);
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason for having multiple individual pipelines, instead of a single pipeline configured with [MaxDegreeOfParallelism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-specify-the-degree-of-parallelism-in-a-dataflow-block)?

Comment: I no longer recall the context in which the question was asked unfortunately.

Comment: No problem my friend. These days I am reading old questions in the tpl-dataflow tag, and I am asking people clarifications about their years-old problems. :-)

Answer (score 1):

In general I don't think what you're looking for is pre-made in Dataflow as it may be with a ConsistentHashing router. However, by adding an id to the pieces of data you wish to flow you can process them in any order, in parallel and reorder them when the processing finishes.

```
public class Message {
        public int MessageId { get; set; }
        public int GroupId { get; set; }        
        public int Value { get; set; }
    }

    public class MessageProcessing
    {
        public void abc() {
            var count = 10000;
            var groups = 5;
            var source = Enumerable.Range(0, count);

            //buffer all input
            var buffer = new BufferBlock<IEnumerable<int>>();

            //split each input enumerable into processing groups
            var messsageProducer = new TransformManyBlock<IEnumerable<int>, Message>(ints => 
            ints.Select((i, index) => new Message() { MessageId = index, GroupId = index % groups, Value = i }).ToList());

            //process each message, one action block may process any group id in any order
            var processMessage = new TransformBlock<Message, Message>(msg => 
            {
                msg.Value++;
                return msg;
            }, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = groups
            });

            //output of processed message values
            int[] output = new int[count];

            //insert messages into array in the order the started in
            var regroup = new ActionBlock<Message>(msg => output[msg.MessageId] = msg.Value, 
                new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions() {
                    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 1
                });
        }        

    }
```

In the example the GroupId of a message isn't used but it could be used in a more complete example for coordinating groups of messages. Also, handling follow up posts to the bufferblock could be done by changing the output array to a List and setting up a corresponding list element each time an enumerable of integers is posted to the buffer block. Depending on your exact use, you may need to support multiple users of the output, and this can be folded back into the flow.

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically create a pipeline with [linking the blocks between each other](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt604564.aspx) based on predicate:

```
var count = 100;
var processingGroups = 5;
var source = Enumerable.Range(1, count);

var buffer = new BufferBlock<int>();
var consumer1 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {  });
var consumer2 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {  });
var consumer3 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {  });
var consumer4 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => { Console.WriteLine(i); });
var consumer5 = new ActionBlock<int>(i => {  });

buffer.LinkTo(consumer1, i => i % 5 == 1);
buffer.LinkTo(consumer2, i => i % 5 == 2);
buffer.LinkTo(consumer3, i => i % 5 == 3);
buffer.LinkTo(consumer4, i => i % 5 == 4);
buffer.LinkTo(consumer5);

foreach (var i in source)
{
    buffer.Post(i);
    // consider async option if you able to do it
    // await buffer.SendAsync(i);
}
buffer.Complete();
Console.ReadLine();
```

The code above will write only numbers from 4th group, processing other groups silently, but I hope you got the idea. There is a general practice to link a block for at least one consumer without filtering for messages not being dropped if they aren't accepted by any consumers, and you can do this if you don't have a default handler ([`NullTarget<int>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh462765.aspx) simply ignores all the messages it got):

```
buffer.LinkTo(DataflowBlock.NullTarget<int>());
```

The downside of this is a continuation of it's advantages: you have to provide predicates, as there is no built-in structures for this. However, it still could be done.